# matplotlib: histogram is not displaying correctly

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, histogram

I have extracted certain data from a csv file contains the information I need to analyze. Made them into a DataFrame. Then group them based on the type of region they are at "reg."

```
datafileR = datafile = pd.read_csv("pixel_data.csv")
datafileR = pd.DataFrame(datafileR)
### Counting the number of each rows based on the "Reg":
datafileR["Reg"].value_counts()
```

This is the result I received:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSJXr.jpg)

Make a group called region based on the Reg column from dataframe: datafileR:

```
region = datafileR.groupby(["Reg"])
```

Now plot them in histogram:

```
sns.set_theme()
plt.hist(datafileR["Reg"].value_counts(), bins=[70,100,130,160,190],color=["grey"],
         histtype='bar', align='mid', orientation='vertical', rwidth=0.85)
```

This is the image I received, but there should have five categories (Middle East and North Africa, Africa (excl MENA),Asia and Pacific, Europe and Eurasia and Cross-regional)on the x-axies. I am not sure what when wrong. Meanwhile, how to change the states on the y-axis so it displays the actual number?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkYAx.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to draw a bar plot, not a histogram. Please ref to https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar

```
datafileR = pd.DataFrame({'reg': np.random.choice(['Asia','Africa','Europe'], size=1000)})
df = datafileR['reg'].value_counts()
plt.bar(x=df.index, height=df.values)
```

[image]
You can also use pandas' plotting functions:

```
df.plot.bar()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: It's a spot on! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. If that solution resolved your problem, consider accepting the answer using the checkmark on the left to close the topic. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I voted up with the solution you kindly provided. Although I do have another question regarding to plotting with different index into bar chart. Will open up another thread about it. Thank you, Diziet.